# wcf application configuration for service reference

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to connect to an external corporate service reference over the internet using the Add Service Reference menu in Visual Studio express 2013.

I keep getting an error:

```
The remote server returned an error(415) Cannont process the message because the content
type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 
'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
```

Do I have to add something in the App.config file?

Comment: Is it a web service or WCF service?

Comment: the address IT gave me is of the format.  https://wcf.xxxxxx.com/servicename/service.svc

Comment: @Riz - WCF **IS** a web service.  Usually SOAP, but can also be RESTful.

Comment: True. I asked to confirm if they provided you wsdl or svc link. This error comes in if client and server use different SOAP version i.e. SOAP 1.1 & 1.2. Can you test; Select Add service reference and then 'Add Web Reference'. In the url paste the link with ?wsdl appended at the end. Can you see the methods exposed by the service?

Comment: Yeah I got a list of methods from the server

Comment: Cool! Now can you add its reference and call a method to see if it works?

Comment: I keep getting a timed out error though that might be network issues related. are there any alternative options?

Comment: if I use ?xsd rather than ?wsdl then I can get a connection and create the reference where as ?wsdl always times out. Why is this tha case?